# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have installed an older version of ExpressJS (`npm i express@3 -g`) and had problems with express generator. After i typed `express -s -e` in shell i got:

```
    $ express -s -e

   create : .

   install dependencies:
     $ cd . && npm install

   run the app:
     $ node app

fs.js:157
  throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:157:9)
    at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1276:14)
    at write (C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\bin\express:41
2:6)
    at C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\bin\express:385:5
    at C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\bin\express:427:11
    at C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\node_modules\mkdirp\i
ndex.js:48:26
```

My system is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I met this,my node version was 10.0.0,and I **changed its version to 9.11.2**. This worked for me. You could change node to old version. hope it helpful.